# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "active_storage_blob_statement"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to convert my Rails application from using Paperclip to Active Storage for file attachments. I'm following a guide/tutorial that outlines how to do this through a migration. However, when I run the migration, I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "active_storage_blob_statement"
LINE 1: active_storage_blob_statement
        ^
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:61:in `block (4 levels) in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:54:in `each'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:53:in `each'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:33:in `each'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:33:in `block in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:32:in `up'
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to fix it. Here's the relevant code from my migration:

```
class ConvertToActiveStorage < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  require 'open-uri'

  def up
    # postgres
    get_blob_id = 'LASTVAL()'
    # mariadb
    # get_blob_id = 'LAST_INSERT_ID()'
    # sqlite
    # get_blob_id = 'LAST_INSERT_ROWID()'

    # Prepare two insert statements for the new ActiveStorage tables
    active_storage_blob_statement = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare('active_storage_blob_statement', <<-SQL)
      INSERT INTO active_storage_blobs (
        key, filename, content_type, metadata, byte_size, checksum, created_at
      ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, '{}', $4, $5, $6)
    SQL

    active_storage_attachment_statement = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare('active_storage_attachment_statement', <<-SQL)
      INSERT INTO active_storage_attachments (
        name, record_type, record_id, blob_id, created_at
      ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, #{get_blob_id}, $4)
    SQL
    

    # Eager load the application so that all Models are available
    Rails.application.eager_load!

    # Get a list of all the models in the application
    models = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.reject(&:abstract_class?)

    transaction do
      models.each do |model|
        # If the model has a column or columns named *_file_name,
        # We are assuming this is a column added by Paperclip.
        # Store the name of the attachment(s) found (e.g. "avatar") in an array named attachments
        attachments = model.column_names.map do |c|
          if c =~ /(.+)_file_name$/
            $1
          end
        end.compact

        # If no Paperclip columns were found in this model, go to the next model
        if attachments.blank?
          puts '  No Paperclip attachment columns found for [' + model.to_s + '].'
          puts ''
          next
        end

        puts '  Paperclip attachment columns found for [' + model.to_s + ']: ' + attachments.to_s

        # Loop through the records of the model, and then through each attachment definition within the model
        model.find_each.each do |instance|
          attachments.each do |attachment|
            # If the model record doesn't have an uploaded attachment, skip to the next record
            if instance.send(attachment).path.blank?
              next
            end

            # Otherwise, we will convert the Paperclip data to ActiveStorage records
            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
              'active_storage_blob_statement', [
                key(instance, attachment),
                instance.send("#{attachment}_file_name"),
                instance.send("#{attachment}_content_type"),
                instance.send("#{attachment}_file_size"),
                checksum(instance.send(attachment)),
                instance.updated_at.iso8601
              ])

            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
              'active_storage_attachment_statement', [
                attachment,
                model.name,
                instance.id,
                instance.updated_at.iso8601,
              ])
          end
        end
      end
    end

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('DEALLOCATE PREPARE active_storage_attachment_statement')
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('DEALLOCATE PREPARE active_storage_blob_statement')
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end

  private

  def key(instance, attachment)
    # SecureRandom.uuid
    # Alternatively:
    filename = instance.send("#{attachment}_file_name")
    klass = instance.class.table_name
    id = instance.id
    id_partition = ("%09d".freeze % id).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/".freeze)

    "#{klass}/#{attachment.pluralize}/#{id_partition}/original/#{filename}"
  end

  def checksum(attachment)
    # local files stored on disk:
    url = attachment.path
    Digest::MD5.base64digest(File.read(url))

    # remote files stored on another person's computer:
    # url = attachment.url
    # Digest::MD5.base64digest(Net::HTTP.get(URI(url)))
  end
end
```

I've tried using exec_prepared instead of execute

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_prepared(
  'active_storage_blob_statement', [
    key(instance, attachment),
    instance.send("#{attachment}_file_name"),
    instance.send("#{attachment}_content_type"),
    instance.send("#{attachment}_file_size"),
    checksum(instance.send(attachment)),
    instance.updated_at.iso8601
  ])

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_prepared(
  'active_storage_attachment_statement', [
    attachment,
    model.name,
    instance.id,
    instance.updated_at.iso8601,
  ])
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
Did you mean?  exec_update
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:61:in `block (4 levels) in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:54:in `each'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:53:in `each'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:33:in `each'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:33:in `block in up'
/myapp/db/migrate/20230313230800_convert_to_active_storage.rb:32:in `up'

Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `exec_prepared'
```

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prepare the statement you need to use `prepare` of the raw postgres connection (as you did) and then to execute, you need to use `exec_prepared` of the raw postgres connection again.

`execute` is a method on the AR connection that you can use to execute a normal SQL statement :-(

```
Something.connection.raw_connection.prepare('some-name', "select count(*) from somethings")
=> #<PG::Result:0x000000401f888f38 status=PGRES_COMMAND_OK ntuples=0 nfields=0 cmd_tuples=0>
irb(main):003:0> Something.connection.raw_connection.exec_prepared("some-name")
=> #<PG::Result:0x000000401fcc63c0 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=1 nfields=1 cmd_tuples=1>
irb(main):004:0>
```

In short:

Change

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`

to

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.exec_prepared`